# Javascript Data Lineage To Pin Point External Calls and Intermediate Calculations

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-chrome, debugging, browser

I am debugging a website to understand why an element has certain value because it doesn't match what we observed in the database.

It is a complex system and there are layers of business logic that led to what showed up on the site, some implemented in the front end, some in the backend, also cannot rule out there are conflicting logics or bugs.

Is there a way to capture the data lineage like to inspect an element in Chrome Dev tool and  it will show me the full data lineage to reproduce what showed up on the site?

This screenshot is an oversimplification of a possible scenarios where a node contains the final number (eg. inventory availability).

[image]